# Why there is no error from the wrong enum class in switch statement in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-c++, c++11, enums

This snippet of code fails to compile in g++ 4.8.1 (see http://ideone.com/hk3Ewt), but works in Visual Studio 2013 Update 1. I'm interested, is it some well known error in the Visual C++ compiler or this code is allowed by standard and gcc is just too restrictive? If it's okay then enum classes are a bit meaningless in my opinion.

I have to say in the defense of Visual Studio, that Intellisense tries to underscore the wrong lines as errors, but I'm interested in compiler diagnostics.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

enum class A
{
    foo,
    bar
};

enum class B
{
    baz,
    foo
};

int main() {
    A a = A::foo;

    switch (a)
    {
        case B::baz: cout << "B::baz"; break;
        case B::foo: cout << "B::foo"; break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Both GCC and Clang reject the code correctly, this is a bug in VS.

Comment: Agreed; please open a bug on [Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/visualstudio) and reply back here with a link

Comment: @JamesMcNellis Done: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/859012/

Comment: Still happens with Visual Studio Update 3. I'm afraid they also closed the bug report on this. Fortunately Intellisense recognizes the error (which makes their compiler look even worse).

Comment: @Excelcius: they've closed my issue as a duplicate of another one http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedbackdetail/view/875616

Comment: Oh, thanks, didn't notice that. Connect was sort of broken last time I looked and I believe it said something like "Not solvable".